# D7 + Views: How to hide fields labels?

Tags: views, nodes

I have set all my fields labels as hidden in content types > display fields.

It seems like Views overrides this by displaying labels of the filter fields.

How to hide them?

Comment: Is the row style (see Format>Show on the view edit page) of your view set to "Fields" or "Content"?

Answer (score 3):

Click on the field in the filter section, and you'll see a "Label" option.